# Pytorch doing a cross entropy loss when the predictions already have probabilities

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, probability, pytorch, softmax

So, normally categorical cross-entropy could be applied using a cross-entropy loss function in PyTorch or by combing a logsoftmax with the negative log likelyhood function such as follows:

```
m  = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
loss = nn.NLLLoss()
pred   = torch.tensor([[-1,0,3,0,9,0,-7,0,5]], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
target = torch.tensor([4])
output = loss(m(pred), target)
print(output)
```

The thing is.  What if the data at the output is already in a state with the probabilities where the variable pred already has the probabilities.  Where the data is presented like the following:

```
pred = torch.tensor([[.25,0,0,0,.5,0,0,.25,0]], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
```

How could the cross-entropy then be completed in PyTorch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement categorical cross entropy pretty easily yourself. It is calculated as

$$
\text{cross-entropy} = -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^m \mathbf{y}_{ij} \log \hat{\mathbf{y}}_{ij}
$$

where $n$ is the number of samples in your batch, $m$ is the number of classes, $\mathbf{y}_i$ is the one-hot target for example $i$, $\mathbf{\hat{y}}_i$ is the predicted probability distribution, and $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ refers to the $j$-th element of this array.

In PyTorch:

```py
def categorical_cross_entropy(y_pred, y_true):
    y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, 1e-9, 1 - 1e-9)
    return -(y_true * torch.log(y_pred)).sum(dim=1).mean()
```

You can then use `categorical_cross_entropy` just as you would `NLLLoss` in the training of a model. The reason that we have the `torch.clamp` line is to ensure that we have no zero elements, which will cause `torch.log` to produce `nan` or `inf`.

One difference you'll have to make in your code is that this version expects a one-hot target rather than an integer target. You can easily convert your current target list like so:

```py
one_hot_targets = torch.eye(NUM_CLASSES)[targets]
```

where `targets` is a `torch.tensor` with integer values and `NUM_CLASSES` is the number of output classes that you have.

Comment: OK, well, I didn't expect that to work, but when I tried the code it did.  Clearly, I'm not understanding properly.  I'll have to play around with a bit till I figure it out.  Cheers for that!

Comment: @user3023715 No worries, if you have any specific questions I can elaborate further if you like!

Comment: Well, what about calculating perplexity via using categorical_cross_entropy from this. Should it be 2^cce or e^cee? @timleathart